# pubsub notification when stop reads stream message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

i created pubsub topic reads streaming messages and ingest to BQ. i want to create a notification/alert to the team when the pubsub stop read the messages. could you please guide for the implementation.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you set up?

Comment: i need to send a mail notification when i dont receive any streaming message from consumer. how will i achieve?

Comment: Do you have PubSUb subscription?